# FileLoadException in ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app when deployed to Azure App Service linux?

Tags: c#, linux, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

I published my pretty simple ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app to Azure App Service linux. And I get some weird FileLoadException. The error log is long and **does NOT have enough info** to fix the problem!

```
 System.InvalidOperationException:
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Array.Sort (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory+<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetCallSite>b__0 (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd (System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateArgumentCallSites (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.TryCreateExact (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory+<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<GetCallSite>b__0 (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd (System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.GetCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.CreateServiceAccessor (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd (System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at lambda_method (Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelActivatorProvider+<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateActivator>b__0 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreateModelFactory>b__0 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.CreateInstance (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageActionInvoker+<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__22.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware+<<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware+<<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
Inner exception System.IO.FileLoadException handled at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort:
   at System.Signature.GetSignature (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.get_Signature (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParametersNoCopy (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.GetParameters (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory+<>c.<CreateConstructorCallSite>b__16_1 (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=3.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.SwapIfGreater (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntroSort (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.IntrospectiveSort (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Collections.Generic.ArraySortHelper`1.Sort (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
```

Obviously, it works locally.
Can someone please provide a clue on this?

#UPDATE

Here's my .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI" Version="3.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" Version="5.2.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="3.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\<MyClassLib>\<MyClassLib>.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and class lib .csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="MyAuthNetStandardPackage" Version="1.0.0-CI-20200701-185647" />
    <PackageReference Include="MyHelpersValidatorsPackage" Version="1.0.0-CI-20200124-161720" />
    <PackageReference Include="MyHelpersValidatorsUtils" Version="1.0.0-CI-20200124-161720" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Yes, there are dependencies, of course. But missing file information must be reported SOMEHOW anyway.

Comment: Can you share your solution csproj ?

Comment: @Melchia - added.

Comment: Can you provide the core code for file operations? From the error message, we can see that there is an error in `ArrySortHelper`. You need to follow up the code to find the problem.

Comment: I do not work with files in this project at all. Yes, I also want to follow up the code but I have the same question - how would I do that when there seems like my code is not involved and no info on which file is missing whatsoever...